# Can you write to Firebase when successfully created new user?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am having a problem storing extra information about the newly created user

```
myFirebaseRef.createUser(email, pass, new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {

@Override
public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result)
{
myFirebaseRef.child("Users").child(result.get("uid")).setValue(screenname);
}
});
```

Is it allowed to write in onSuccess to Firebase?

**UPDATE**

I have the following rule

```
"Users" :{
  "$user_id" :{
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "$user_id==auth.uid"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

The problem is with the rule, as the auth.uid is not available untill the user is logged in using the authWithPassword method. So in my case permission is denied.
But how can I limited the write to the location only to the user creating it if they are not logged in yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two actions going on:

1. create a user
2. save the user's data to the database

You have an `onSuccess()` handler for #1, but not for #2. What you need to do is [add a completion listener](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-completion-callback):

```
myFirebaseRef
  .child("Users")
  .child(result.get("uid"))
  .setValue(screenname, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
        if (firebaseError != null) {
            System.out.println("Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Will this work with the rule above? I thought that the auth.uid won't be availabe untill the user is logged in, so I can't limit writing to the location untill the user log in.

Comment: Ah, true. So you'll have to add an `ref.authWithPassword()` call in the middle there. It's turning into a nicely nested callstack, but should work.