# How to set this Firebase rules?

Tags: json, firebase

I am stuck on how to solve the security for my app here.

I have this structure:

[image]

Users shouldn't be able to write to points, but able to write to nickname.
Is this possible?

I tried this rule but it doesn't work

```
"Users" :{
  "$user_id" :{
    "Points" :{
      ".read" : true,
      ".write" : false
    },
    "nickname" :{
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "$user_id==auth.uid"
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Splitting the data to two node is a solution to one part of the problem, leaving the other part of the problem which is writing the nickname.
Writing the nickname should only be possible by the user whom the nickname belong to, but in my code, I am asking the user to put email, pass and nickname.
When the user is registring, the auth.uid is not available yet, I considered registering the user under temporary name and they change it later after they log in, but I am looking for a shorter solution where they get to pick the name when registering

This is my bit of code when they register:

```
Ref.createUser(email, pass, 
  new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
      Ref2 = new Firebase(firebase_users_path + result.get("uid").toString());
      HashMap<String, String> names = new HashMap<String, String>();
      names.put("nickname", nickname);
      Ref2.setValue(names, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
          if (firebaseError != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
      });
```

My code is returning Done! indicating registering is complete, I do find a new user but the nickname doesn't get written in users/uid because the auth.uid is not available yet

Comment: "it doesn't work" is unfortunately incredibly broad. What operation do you try to do? Show the code of the read/write that fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A broad guess (since the code that fails is missing) is that you're trying to write a user record:

```
 ref.child('Users').child(auth.uid).set({ 'nickname': 'masood' });
```

This operation will fail, since the user doesn't have write access to the user node.

For this reason (and quite some others) it's better to split the data into separate nodes that the user has different access types to. In your case:

```
User_names
    0a88b...
        nickname: "First_user"
User_scores
    0a88b...
        Points: 35
```

Now you can secure it easily *and* one level higher:

```
"User_names" :{
  "$user_id" :{
    "nickname" :{
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "$user_id==auth.uid"
    }
  }
},
"User_points" :{
  "$user_id" :{
    "Points" :{
      ".read" : true,
      ".write" : false
    }
  }
}
```

You might even want to pull the `.read` up to a higher level, so that anyone can *list* user names and scores:

```
"User_names" :{
  ".read": true,
  "$user_id" :{
    "nickname" :{
      ".write": "$user_id==auth.uid"
    }
  }
},
"User_points" :{
  ".read" : true,
  "$user_id" :{
    "Points" :{
      ".write" : false
    }
  }
}
```

There's a pretty good section in the [Firebase docs on how rules cannot be used to filter data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I think splitting the data is part of the solution, but I still would have the problem of writing the nickname while registering the user. I have updated the question.

Comment: As I [commented on your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234664/can-you-write-to-firebase-when-successfully-created-new-user/34235459?noredirect=1#comment56216399_34235459), you'll need to first authenticate the user before saving their data. So first register, then authenticate, only then save user data.